# Google maps and white space errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have built an app that lets my client input a title, lat, long and content. All works fine until they include some white space in their code, then google map just refuses to work. What's the best way of preventing this? My current code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Google map
function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  // Create map on #map_canvas
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // Define boundarys
  var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var countries = [

    {title : 'M11 Moscow to St. Petersburg', lat : 55.938818, lon : 37.429733, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker.png', content : '<h4>M11 Moscow to St. Petersburg</h4><p>The M11 is a 650 km highway project aimed at connecting Moscow to Saint Petersburg. Despite several options proposed to build it, it was decided in 2009 that the road would run through Khimki Forest (between the 18 and 58 km marks), a centuries-old oak trees forest and host of many species of wildlife.</p><p>This decision provoked number of protests. On December 24 2011, nearly 100.000 persons rallied in Moscow, the largest demonstration in Russia since the fall of the Soviet Union.</p><p>The European Bank for Reconstruction and Development and the European Investment Bank, initially part of project, decided in 2011 to withdrawn their support.</p><p>The part of the road going through the forest is funded by private consortium including French giant construction group Vinci. Environmentalists and local residents denounce a case of corruption aimed at enriching property developers eager to increase housing facilities at the outskirts of Moscow.</p><p>The case of the M11 is also notorious because of the many reports of police brutality, intimidations, beatings and death of protesters and journalists.</p><p>The highway is due to open in 2014</p>'},
    {title : 'Title', lat : 1.576339, lon : 100.969849, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker_blue.png', content : '<h4>Title</h4><p>On the island of Sumatra in Indonesia, one of the world's richest ecosystem and host of the critically endangered sumatran elephant, rhinoceros, tiger and orangutan, road-building through intact forests and protected areas is a recurrent theme.</p><p>Kerinci Seblat,</p><p>The 1.33m ha Kerinci Seblat National Park (KSNP) in West Sumatra, is strictly protected under Indonesian law and an ASEAN Heritage Site and a UNESCO World Heritage Site.</p><p>Despite being illegal, plans to open four roads (up to 12 meters wide) through the park have been regularly supported by Aceh's consecutive governors for the last few years. For the local environmental NGOs denouncing the risks of fragmenting intact forest, destroying vulnerable ecosystems, and dividing breeding grounds and movement corridors, these plans are an aberration.</p><p>In June 2011, the Association for Tropical Biology and Conservation (ATBC) has drafted a resolution urging the Indonesian government to cancel plans to build roads through KSNP, the country's oldest national park.</p><p>Aceh,</p><p>The Ladia-Galaska road network planned consists in building 450 kilometres of main road plus more than 1200 kilometres of minor roads. It would turn 2.5m ha of rainforest into a patchwork of forest islands (see GIS model picture). This project has been discussed for a decade. Under the influence of various NGOs and external political intervention from the European Union, the project has so far been kept at bay.</p><p>In both cases, the following patterns have been identified:</p><p>Constant spatial revision plans to convert protected forests in production forests.</p><p>- Existence of roads often legitimises these spatial revision plans. Once a road is built, the forest is opened to logging, mining and others industrial activities.</p><p>- Logic is missing: some roads do not connect to human population centres of sufficiently large size or will cut through watershed forest in areas already prone to severe flooding.</p><p>Viable alternatives to constructing new routes do exist. They would be better for the biodiversity and better for the local populations.</p>'},
    {title : 'Title of third movement', lat : 3, lon : 3, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker_green.png', content : '<h4>Title of third movement</h4><p>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris…</p>'},
    {title : 'Title of fouth movement', lat : 24, lon : 52, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker_red.png', content : '<h4>Title of fouth movement</h4><p>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris…</p>'},
    {title : 'Title of fifth movement', lat : -24, lon : -24, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker.png', content : '<h4>Title of fifth movement</h4><p>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris…</p>'},

  ];

  // Create markers
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        var c = countries[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat, c.lon);
        c.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: c.marker,
            title: c.title});
        c.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: c.content});
        google.maps.event.addListener(c.marker, 'click', makeCallback(c));
        // Create marker bounds
        markerBounds.extend(latlng);
    }

  // Create info windows based on above content
  function makeCallback(country) {
      return function () {
          country.infowindow.open(map, country.marker);
      };
  }

  // Fit map to marker boundaries
  map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

}
</script>
```

I basically want to strip out any whitespace from the content option, any ideas appreciated!

Comment: It has most certainly nothing to do with google maps, but the way you pass the users input.

Comment: Where is content option in your code??

Comment: It's within the countries array, to output it we're doing: {initiative_map}{title : '{initiative_map:title}', lat : {initiative_map:lat}, lon : {initiative_map:long}, marker : '{initiative_map:marker}', content : '<h4>{initiative_map:title}</h4>{initiative_map:body}'},{/initiative_map}

Comment: Problem is probably due to the ' in `one of the world's richest ecosystem` that is prematurely closing the content string of your second country.  Strongly suggest running your JS through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to identify all your syntax errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with whitespace.  It's everything to do with un-escaped single-quotation marks in your content strings that is prematurely ending the strings.  This, and other JS syntax errors, will prevent Google Maps working.

You can escape them by prepending with `\` e.g. try this instead:

```
//Google map
function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  // Create map on #map_canvas
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // Define boundarys
  var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var countries = [

    {title : 'M11 Moscow to St. Petersburg', lat : 55.938818, lon : 37.429733, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker.png', content : '<h4>M11 Moscow to St. Petersburg</h4><p>The M11 is a 650 km highway project aimed at connecting Moscow to Saint Petersburg. Despite several options proposed to build it, it was decided in 2009 that the road would run through Khimki Forest (between the 18 and 58 km marks), a centuries-old oak trees forest and host of many species of wildlife.</p><p>This decision provoked number of protests. On December 24 2011, nearly 100.000 persons rallied in Moscow, the largest demonstration in Russia since the fall of the Soviet Union.</p><p>The European Bank for Reconstruction and Development and the European Investment Bank, initially part of project, decided in 2011 to withdrawn their support.</p><p>The part of the road going through the forest is funded by private consortium including French giant construction group Vinci. Environmentalists and local residents denounce a case of corruption aimed at enriching property developers eager to increase housing facilities at the outskirts of Moscow.</p><p>The case of the M11 is also notorious because of the many reports of police brutality, intimidations, beatings and death of protesters and journalists.</p><p>The highway is due to open in 2014</p>'},
    {title : 'Title', lat : 1.576339, lon : 100.969849, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker_blue.png', content : '<h4>Title</h4><p>On the island of Sumatra in Indonesia, one of the world\'s richest ecosystem and host of the critically endangered sumatran elephant, rhinoceros, tiger and orangutan, road-building through intact forests and protected areas is a recurrent theme.</p><p>Kerinci Seblat,</p><p>The 1.33m ha Kerinci Seblat National Park (KSNP) in West Sumatra, is strictly protected under Indonesian law and an ASEAN Heritage Site and a UNESCO World Heritage Site.</p><p>Despite being illegal, plans to open four roads (up to 12 meters wide) through the park have been regularly supported by Aceh\'s consecutive governors for the last few years. For the local environmental NGOs denouncing the risks of fragmenting intact forest, destroying vulnerable ecosystems, and dividing breeding grounds and movement corridors, these plans are an aberration.</p><p>In June 2011, the Association for Tropical Biology and Conservation (ATBC) has drafted a resolution urging the Indonesian government to cancel plans to build roads through KSNP, the country\'s oldest national park.</p><p>Aceh,</p><p>The Ladia-Galaska road network planned consists in building 450 kilometres of main road plus more than 1200 kilometres of minor roads. It would turn 2.5m ha of rainforest into a patchwork of forest islands (see GIS model picture). This project has been discussed for a decade. Under the influence of various NGOs and external political intervention from the European Union, the project has so far been kept at bay.</p><p>In both cases, the following patterns have been identified:</p><p>Constant spatial revision plans to convert protected forests in production forests.</p><p>- Existence of roads often legitimises these spatial revision plans. Once a road is built, the forest is opened to logging, mining and others industrial activities.</p><p>- Logic is missing: some roads do not connect to human population centres of sufficiently large size or will cut through watershed forest in areas already prone to severe flooding.</p><p>Viable alternatives to constructing new routes do exist. They would be better for the biodiversity and better for the local populations.</p>'},
    {title : 'Title of third movement', lat : 3, lon : 3, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker_green.png', content : '<h4>Title of third movement</h4><p>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris…</p>'},
    {title : 'Title of fouth movement', lat : 24, lon : 52, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker_red.png', content : '<h4>Title of fouth movement</h4><p>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris…</p>'},
    {title : 'Title of fifth movement', lat : -24, lon : -24, marker : 'http://roadfree.org/images/map_markers/icon_map-marker.png', content : '<h4>Title of fifth movement</h4><p>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris…</p>'}
  ];

  // Create markers
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        var c = countries[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat, c.lon);
        c.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: c.marker,
            title: c.title});
        c.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: c.content});
        google.maps.event.addListener(c.marker, 'click', makeCallback(c));
        // Create marker bounds
        markerBounds.extend(latlng);
    }

  // Create info windows based on above content
  function makeCallback(country) {
      return function () {
          country.infowindow.open(map, country.marker);
      };
  }

  // Fit map to marker boundaries
  map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan, is there anyway I can automate this? It's the client entering the content in via a content management system

Comment: what you need is a function you can run any content through to escape anything like that. Ideally you'd do that server-side before outputting the text into your JS.  But it shouldn't be impossible to do in JS either.

Comment: Thanks, simply put the content : in " instead of ' seems to have fixed this issue!

Comment: ah well, that'll work only so long as the user doesn't put `"` in their content!